What does な mean in the interjection バカな?
I'm curious about how to parse バカな when it's used on its own (i.e. as an interjection). Is な used in the な-adjective sense, implying that the phrase is an ellipsis for バカなことがありえない (or something like that)? Or, is it being used as the sentence-final particle, e.g. バカ(だ)な?
EDIT: I heard it in a videogame when a character loses a round, and the English localization says "No way!" in that same context.

I don't think I've ever seen バカな as an interjection that wasn't really バカなぁ, with the な(ぁ) sentence-ending particle. I think it would make little sense to use an attributive (the な here) and not, well, attribute it to anything.

Need some context but I guess it is an injection for criticizing someone.

I'm having trouble finding a specific audio clip... in hindsight, maybe what I actually heard was そんなバカな (which does have a definition in Jisho, unlike バカな)? And if so, I guess I'm curious about the な in this phrase too.

Just updated the question—and it turns out that what I heard was indeed just バカな on its own.

そんなバカな (which does have a definition in Jisho, unlike バカな) -- Weblio和英辞典 has: 馬鹿な！-- This is ridiculous! No way! Impossible!

My father is from Kanto and sometimes says 「そんなバカな！」/「んなバカな！」/「バカな！」 angrily.

I don't think I've ever seen バカな as an interjection that wasn't really バカなぁ, with the な(ぁ) sentence-ending particle. -- To attach the sentence ending particle な to バカ, it should be バカだなぁ. cf 静かだなぁ。きれいだなあ。 since 終助詞「な」 is attached to 終止形.

If you say バカな on its own, it's always a short-form of そんなバカなことがあるか.
It means something like "no way!" but it's not criticising the conversation partner. The 馬鹿 is directed at the situation and describes how absurd it is, not at a person. It's more like "no fucking way". It can also be used if the situation is simply very surprising (as opposed to being absurd).
It has become somewhat archaic now, and it's uncommon to hear it in real life tho. In manga yes, but in real life if someone used they would appear either joking or カッコつけ.
